# How to automatically attach a DataBase from a given folder path

Tags: sql-server

This question may not be possible to answer but I've exhausted all options on trying to figure this out and this is my last shot.

My plan is that when I receive a database in a specific folder path such as C:\DBFiles, I'd like SQLMS 2013 to automatically recognise the new .MDF and attach the file to my SQLMS.

Would there be such a script to do something such as this?

Comment: You can use a scheduled job or a scheduled task for this -- the former executes within SQL Server, the latter outside. A scheduled task has an easier time doing a `dir`; a scheduled job has an easier time with permissions. Note that you cannot attach an .MDF on its own; you need both data and log files, or else the `ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG` option. It makes slightly more sense to restore a backup instead, especially since you can delete those after you're done. With an .MDF, you'd have to check if you've already attached it every time.

Comment: Good shout with the constant checking. Using a .bak is possible for me. Not familiar with scheduled task or jobs so I'll read up on it however won't it pose the same problem for which you'll need to check to see if the .bak has been restored each time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you've exhausted a search and were unable to come up with anything at all.

Recently I've found PowerShell and the dbatools module (https://dbatools.io/getting-started/) this is pretty freak'n amazing, also amazing you missed a solution of PowerShell in general.

The link will give you a synopsis of things you can do, which include a command line interface, coupled with the windows scheduler task you should be able to do great things. Sounds like you might need some sort of listener approach for when a file is dropped into a file folder.